# Sunspot/SOLR queries using OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I'd like to setup Sunspot for a model as follows:

```
Sunspot.search(Show) do
  with(:id).equal_to MY_QUERY.to_i
  OR
  with(:legacy_id).equal_to MY_QUERY.to_i
end
```

Is there a way to do Sunspot searches where it returns an Show that matches either of the conditions?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any_of

```
Sunspot.search(Show) do
  any_of do
    with(:id).equal_to MY_QUERY.to_i
    with(:legacy_id).equal_to MY_QUERY.to_i
  end
end
```

Hope this helps. 
Thanks.